# What is the meaning of "rider"?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, apocope

For practice recently I found myself picking through "Vesti la Giubba," the aria from Pagliacci, which contains the following line:

> La gente paga, e rider vuole qua.

I understand the general meaning of the line to be "The people pay, and they want to laugh here" but the word "rider" through me for a bit of a loop. Is it just an [apocopic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#apocopic) form of "ridere" or is it something else?

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!

Comment: A comment that may be useful to other people finding this page in future: there is a second modern meaning of [rider](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rider_res-2ddae522-89eb-11e8-a7cb-00271042e8d9_%28Neologismi%29/) in Italian (pronounced like the English word), which is only a few years old and is not found in older dictionaries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, *rider* it just an [apocopic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#apocopic) form of the verb *ridere* (to laugh).

> A word form in which the word is lacking the final sound or syllable. Occurs in Italian, Spanish, and other languages.

Similar cases are *son* for *sono* (I am or they are), *dir* for *dire* (to say) and *san* for *santo* (saint).

From the Treccani dictionary for [apocope](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/apocope/):

> **apòcope** s. f. [dal lat. tardo *apocŏpe*, gr. ἀποκοπή «troncamento», der.
>   di ἀποκόπτω «tagliar via»]. – 1. In linguistica, caduta di una vocale
>   finale e in generale di uno o più fonemi al termine d’una parola, come
>   in ital. *son* per *sono*, *dir* per *dire*; *san* per *santo*; in lat. *dic*, *duc*
>   «di’», «conduci», in luogo di *dice*, *duce*; ha sign. più ampio e meno
>   specifico che troncamento.

As you can see from the definition it comes from Greek and means "to cut out". In linguistics it means the fall of a final vowel of a word and in general of one or more phonemes at the end of a word.

Comment: It may be useful to note that *apocope* is used quite extensively also in spoken Italian, not only for coping with metric constraints in poetry.